# get all topic names in C++ API

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am able to get advertised topics with
**std::liststd::string topics;
topics = gazebo::transport::getAdvertisedTopics("");**
How to get all topics which are present but not advertised/published ( like ~\unit_box\link\wrench , etc. ) is C++ API ?
These topics are visible with **gz topic -l** but how to access in C++ API

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20867/get-all-topic-names-in-c++-api/) by [Gaurav](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6898/gaurav/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here is the code behind `gz topic -l`: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f4e51e8f64001beda70615ab8982a7d5a4e65b18/tools/gz_topic.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#gz_topic.cc-119

Is that what you are looking for?

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2018-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gaurav](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6898/gaurav/) on 2018-10-31**:
Yes. It works. Thanks.

**Comment by [Basti](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43506/basti/) on 2021-11-15**:
Answer is still valid, but the link is dead. Use https://github.com/arpg/Gazebo/blob/master/tools/gz_topic.cc#L87-L113